# How can i highlight the current song that is being played

Tags: reactjs, audio-player, playlist

Here is the code that displays my playlist.

```
             {data?.map((data, index) => {
                 return(
                  <li 
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    setActive(true)
                      store.addSong(data.assets[0].audio)
                      store.addImage(data.photo)
                      store.addName(data.name)
                      store.addSongIndex(index)
                  }}
                  className={!store.song ? "" : "active"}
                  key={data?.id}>
                  <div className="plItem">
                     <span className="trackNumber">{index + 1}</span> 
                     <span className="trackTitle">
                        <WordLimit limit={35}>
                         {data ? data.name : "word"}
                         </WordLimit> 
                      </span> 
                   </div>
                   </li>
                 )
             } 
              )}
```

So, the onclick function sends the current song to the audio source, updates the image of the song, but i want to highlight the current song that is being played, i want to be able to add probably a dynamic className that works on the songs that is being played on the playlist, in short it is just to differentiate the current played song from the one that is not being played.

I tried adding a className called active dynamically, but instead for it get just a single `<li></li>` it got all, which is not what i want.
Here is how i tried to do it..

```
className={!store.song ? "" : "active"}
```

Comment: What value is in `store.song`? Is it the song id?

Comment: ```store.song``` is an audioUrl

Comment: I see. Does the `data` object have this audio URL in it to do a comparison?

Comment: Yeah, that is where i got the ```store.song``` from.

Comment: So it sounds like you could do something like `className={store.song === data.song ? "highlight" : undefined}` (or maybe it's a different key in `data`)

Comment: hmm, i see.
seems like that will add the ```className="highlight"``` to all the ```<li></li>``` , which is not what i want..

Comment: But, let me try it out first.
will get back to you..

Comment: It should hopefully only match one of the songs in the array, therefore only highlighting the one you want

Comment: Yeahhh, it worked..
Thanks a lot, you have answered my question.

Comment: To answer your questions, you can highlight it in many ways I would go for a yellow border

Comment: Hmmm, alright.
Thanks for the info.

Comment: @OgundipePelumi glad this worked! I added an actual answer; I'd appreciate if you mark it as correct so I can get credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, in your `className` logic, check the current song against the song in the store. If they're equal, that's the highlighted class:

```js
className={store.song === data.song ? "highlight" : undefined}
```

And here it is in context:

```
{data?.map((data, index) => {
  return(
    <li 
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setActive(true)
        store.addSong(data.assets[0].audio)
        store.addImage(data.photo)
        store.addName(data.name)
        store.addSongIndex(index)
      }}
      className={store.song === data.song ? "highlight" : undefined}
      key={data?.id}
    >
    <div className="plItem">
      <span className="trackNumber">{index + 1}</span> 
      <span className="trackTitle">
        <WordLimit limit={35}>
          {data ? data.name : "word"}
        </WordLimit> 
      </span> 
    </div>
  </li>
)})}
```